# Generic and type safe I/O model in any language

Tags: design, io

I am looking for an I/O model, in any programming language, that is *generic* and *type safe*.

By *genericity*, I mean there should not be separate functions for performing the same operations on different devices (`read_file`, `read_socket`, `read_terminal`). Instead, a single `read` operation works on all `read`-able devices, a single `write` operation works on all `write`-able devices, and so on.

By *type safety*, I mean operations that do not make sense should not even be expressible in first place. Using the `read` operation on a non-`read`-able device ought to cause a type error at compile time, similarly for using the `write` operation on a non-`write`-able device, and so on.

Is there any generic and type safe I/O model?

Comment: "Beauty is in the eye of the beholder" and is subjective to the viewer and not a good fit for the Stack Exchange Q&A model.

Comment: @WorldEngineer: If you read carefully into it, basically I was asking for a type safe I/O model, where the type system can be used to enforce that no operation that does not make sense can be even attempted.

Comment: @EduardoLeón - Well if you what you want is a type-safe model, ask about a type-safe model.  Using words like "beautiful" is a distraction.  (Adding the tag "close-me" would have been almost as effective ...)

Comment: But to answer your question, an API that made seeking on a non-seekable file descriptor a compile time error would probably be difficult to use ... and impossible to implement.  (For example, on Linux the only reliable way to tell if an fd is seekable is to try to seek.)

Comment: @StephenC: I never said the API had to be implemented in C. I explicitly said "any language". And IMO there is nothing harder to use than an API that allows you to write and compile nonsense that you will have to manually debug.

Comment: Learn the crap out of file I/O on a platform you care about, validate params to the best of your ability, and write your own API in a language you like.

Comment: @EduardoLeón the file descriptor is the identifier of the stream for the OS for most IO types and passed to the IO system calls, this includes stout and stin (the basic streams)

Comment: The Java API for example allows to read on a input stream and to write on an output stream. And you cannot create an output stream on a file if you do not have write access. From that point on, the type system ensures that you can only call methods provided by the stream object you are using.

Comment: Haskell is also close to this. Especially if you use conduits or pipes

Comment: @jozefg: conduit is a really nice library, but I need file seeking

Comment: @ratchetfreak: I understand that ultimately all I/O relies on APIs that are... written in C, enough said. But that does not mean that it cannot be nicely wrapped so that the wrong cases cannot be triggered.

Comment: @jozefg: And the very pipes tutorial shows that you have to use the `System.IO.Handle` type anyway, which is just as horrible as C's `FILE *`. This is a pity because Haskell does have the type system machinery required to provide a nice I/O API (e.g., type classes `Readable`, `Writeable`, `Seekable`, etc., with instances provided for a wide array of device types), but somehow they seem to think type classes are only for stuff that comes from abstract algebra.

Comment: @Giorgio: Some devices can be used in more complex ways than just unidirectional streams.

Comment: C++ IOStreams fit your requirements. The only things the compiler can't enforce are seekability and access rights for files you try to access, but that is because the information can't be determined until runtime anyway.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau: The behavior of the base `std::istream`, `std::ostream` and `std::iostream` classes when `seekg()`ed and/or `seekp()`ed is unacceptable.

Comment: @EduardoLeón: In what way is their behaviour unacceptable?

Comment: @Bart: All of the behaviour of iostreams is unacceptable, realistically.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau: The existence of `seekg()` and `seekp()` does not provide any guarantee that the stream is indeed seekable. Using `is.seekg()` on some `std::istream is` simply does nothing. So even if it is techinically "safe" to call `seekg()`, this has only been achieved at the cost of sacrificing the true meaning of `seekg()`. You cannot have a `std::istream & is` and say "I am completely sure what `is.seekg()` will do".

Comment: @EduardoLeón: The existence of `istream::operator>>(int)` is also no guarantee that you can read integers from the stream. If that is your main argument, then you are aiming for the impossible.

Comment: @EduardoLeón: If you see a `seekg()` call on a (good) `istream` that does nothing at all, then there are three possibilities: a) you see the result of undefined behaviour (the position did not come from a previous positioning call) b) the custom streambuffer underlying the stream does not follow convention, or c) your implementation is non-conforming.

Answer (score 5):

Having thought some more about this, I think that it can be *proved* that it is not possible to deal with seekability entirely by **compile time** type checking.

- In Linux / Unix there are things called "named sockets" that exist in the file system and can be opened in the same way as other objects in the file system.  The catch is that they are no seekable.  And there are "device files" that have the same property; e.g. "/dev/tty" or "/dev/null".
- An IO library needs to be able to create an input or output stream for an object using a filename or pathname supplied as a string; i.e. a runtime value.  (If you can't do that, the language has "limited utility".)
- The "open" method therefore needs to be able to cope with the cases that it could be asked to open a seekable object or a non-seekable object ... and that it won't know which is the case until it has tried it.
- This means that even if you were to design a set of APIs that distinguished between seekable and non-seekable streams, there would still need to be a runtime test to determine if a specific file *could* be opened as a seekable (or non-seekable) stream.

In short, it is not possible deal with this entirely via static typing.

**UPDATE**

Mat Fennwick commented thus:

> Perhaps I'm missing something, but it seems to me that your example could be handled with an algebraic sum type, à la Haskell. Is that not the case?

Yes, I think that you could express different flavours of stream using algebraic sum types.  But I don't see how this is going to give you a **compilation error** if you:

1. open a stream based on a pathname, then
2. try to do a seek on a non-seekable stream.

You'd end up having to do a `switch` to discriminate the seekable and non-seekable cases, and deal with the possibility that you've got the wrong kind of stream.

---

Now you *could* design the APIs to minimize the runtime checking.  But my feeling is that that comes at a cost.  And the cost is that the classes that *use* the APIs get more complicated.  For instance, whenever you pass a stream object you have to think whether you need to declare the method to require a seekable or non-seekable stream parameter.  (And you can't just say "either" all of the time and use a common supertype ... because then you need a typecast at the point where the stream needs to be seekable and your compiler can no longer detect the real problem.)

The other problem with mapping (effectively) runtime properties to compile time types / interfaces is that it gets messy when you've got multiple; e.g. imagine if you had types / interfaces for seekability, readability, writability, deletability and so on.  You end up with a combinatorial explosion of the leaf classes.

Finally, if this was a good idea, you would have thought that some would have tried it, shown it to be a good idea, and convinced someone to add it to a mainstream programming language.  AFAIK, the last step hasn't happened.  OK, that is not proof that it won't work ... but the absence is pretty convincing.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but it seems to me that your example could be handled with an algebraic sum type, *à la* Haskell.  Is that not the case?

Comment: Hi Stephen, thanks for answering my comment.  However, I'm still not sure that it shows that algebraic sum types won't do the trick.

Comment: @MattFenwick: The problem with algebraic sum types is that, if you have a sum with, say, 3 cases (say, read-only, write-only, read/write), you cannot statically rule out one case (say, write-only) and take the remaining two (say, because you only need to write to the stream). A type-class-based approach would be needed, where the type classes act as type-level "decorators".

Comment: @EduardoLeón sorry, I don't understand your comment.  It reads as "if you use sum types incorrectly, they won't work".

Comment: @MattFenwick: What would your sum type look like, then?

Comment: @EduardoLeón please don't misunderstand my comments.  I'm not claiming to have solved this problem -- all I'm claiming is that I find your and Stephen's arguments against sum types unconvincing.

Answer (score 2):

Java has *"stream readers/writes"*, *"byte readers/writes"*, *"line readers/writes"* that read from and write to "*streams"*. A *"stream"* can be a file, a socket, an url, etc.

Also the language is type safe, strictly typed, compiled, etc. It **yells at compile time** if you attempt to do the wrong operation on the wrong type of stream.

Comment: 1. Is there such a thing as a stream that is both readable and writeable? 2. If so, can I use a R/W stream when a R-only or W-only stream is expected? 3. Can I distinguish seekable streams from nonseekable ones? (This could be useful, say, if I want to guarantee that a parser performs no backtracking.)

Answer (score 1):

You could implement something like this using c++ templates. Boost has a lot of examples of limiting behavior at compile time (eg the graph library). The main hurdle to overcome is the syntax of templates.

Comment: I know technically I could roll my own, but I wanted to avoid reinventing the wheel, especially when I am interested in making cars, not wheels. Namely: http://math.mit.edu/~dspivak/informatics/talks/CTDBIntroductoryTalk (I have been furiously googling for more than two months whether there was any DBMS like that, and there seems to be none, so I am rolling my own.)